# Вставка большого куска кода динамически

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день, прошу проконсультировать по следующему вопросу.
Необходимо с определённым интерваломо времени методом `.prepend()` вставлять крупный блок html-разметки в основной документ. Казалось бы - в чем проблема? Вставляемый блок представляет собою довольно крупное древо со своими стилями. На данный момент скрипт выглядит так:

```
var $cell_content = $('<div class="row_cell"><div class="intro"><span class="intro__date">текст</span><ul class="intro__list"><li class="intro__list__item">текст</li><li class="intro__list__item">текст</li><li class="intro__list__item">текст</li></ul></div></div>');

$('.row:first').prepend($cell_content);
```

Вопрос в следующем: можно ли как-то сократить кол-во символом, да-бы не засорять js-файл, это ведь грузит сервер и создает неприятный моменты. Может быть плагин какой-то или это в принципе невозможно? Буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: С определенным интервалом времени запускайте ajax-запрос, который будет возвращать Вам нужный кусок разметки, а Вы затем будете prepend'ить его куда нужно.

Comment: каким образом клиентский код может грузить сервер?

Comment: @Grundy, я имею ввиду размер файла.js

Comment: @DaemonHK, в общем ajax'ом - лучший из возможных вариантов, вы считаете?

Comment: А ещё лучше оставить как есть

Comment: @denisChunihin, как вариант стоит рассмотреть, все лучше, чем верстку в js хранить